# How to make up a query param in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
before do
  if something
    params[:user] = 'James'
  end
end
post '/' do
  'Hello, ' + params[:user]
end
```

In other words, I want my home page to say `Hello, James` either when it is opened as `/?user=James` or when `something` happens. The code above doesn't work. What is the right approach?

Comment: This code appears to work ok for me. What happens for you?

Comment: @matt my bad, in my case it's `post`, not `get`. I updated the question.

Comment: Still works fine with `POST` for me. The only thing I’ve changed is the `something` bit. Are you sure your condition is true?